# CFDataCreateWithBytesNoCopy() wont work with "const char var[xx]" but will with malloc?

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, core-foundation

Just really looking for an explanation of the following, if the variable **digest** isn't allocated manually then data returned by  **CFDataCreateWithBytesNoCopy()** continuously changes when referenced throughout the program.

```
CFDataRef sha1(CFStringRef string)
{
    unsigned char* digest = malloc(CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH);

    const char* cData  = CFStringGetCStringPtr(string, CFStringGetFastestEncoding(string));
    CC_SHA1(cData, strlen(cData), digest);
    CFDataRef sha = CFDataCreateWithBytesNoCopy(kCFAllocatorDefault, digest, CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH, kCFAllocatorDefault);
    free(digest);
    CFRelease(string);
    return sha;
}
```

Where as this wont work...

```
CFDataRef sha1(CFStringRef string)
{
    unsigned char digest[CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH];

    const char* cData  = CFStringGetCStringPtr(string, CFStringGetFastestEncoding(string));
    CC_SHA1(cData, strlen(cData), digest);
    CFDataRef sha = CFDataCreateWithBytesNoCopy(kCFAllocatorDefault, digest, CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH, kCFAllocatorDefault);
    return sha;
}
```

Also are there any memory leaks in the top code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Second parameter of [CFDataCreateWithBytesNoCopy](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFOundation/Reference/CFDataRef/Reference/reference.html) is a *"pointer to the byte buffer to be used as the backing store of the CFData object"* and in the Discussion section, you will find *"the created object does not copy the external buffer to internal storage but instead uses the buffer as its backing store"*.

Now in your code `unsigned char digest[CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH];` is an array with automatic storage duration, which means that it is deallocated once the execution leaves the scope where it is defined.

Note that documentation also states that *the external buffer* is deallocated *when the CFData object is deallocated*.